# how to set name for checkbox in ListView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

**i want set name for check box and use in code for post method for api**

```
<ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding}">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <controls:CheckBox DefaultText="{Binding Name}" />
                         </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
               </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you had used MVVM . I suggest that you should handle all logic in your ViewModel .You can get the value and index of `CheckBox` in ViewModel.

I used the `CheckBox`  plugin from https://github.com/enisn/Xamarin.Forms.InputKit .

#### in your xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App12"
             xmlns:input="clr-namespace:Plugin.InputKit.Shared.Controls;assembly=Plugin.InputKit"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="contentPage" // set the name of content page
             x:Class="xxx.MainPage">
```

```
<ListView x:Name="listview" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <ViewCell>
              <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#eee" Orientation="Vertical">
                 <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                     <input:CheckBox Text="{Binding Name}" Type="Check" IsChecked="{Binding IsCheck,Mode=TwoWay}" CheckChangedCommand="{Binding Source={x:Reference contentPage}, Path=BindingContext.CheckCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
                 </StackLayout>
              </StackLayout>
           </ViewCell>
       </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

#### in your model

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
       
  protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
  {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  public string Name { get; set; }

  private bool isCheck;
  public bool IsCheck
  {
     get
     {
        return isCheck;
     }

     set
     {
       if (isCheck != value)
       {
          isCheck = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged();
       }
     }
   }


}
```

#### in Viewmodel or Code behind

```
public ObservableCollection<Model> MyItems { get; set; }

public ICommand CheckCommand { get; private set; }

public YourViewModel()
{
  
  MyItems = new ObservableCollection<Model>() {

     new Model(){Name="xxx",IsCheck=true },
     //...
  
  };

           
  CheckCommand = new Command((arg)=> {

    var model = arg as Model; 

    for(int i=0;i<MyItems.Count;i++)
    {
        if (model == MyItems[i])
        {
           // i is the index that you checked
                      
           bool ischeck = MyItems[i].IsCheck;

           // do some thing you want 
        }
    }

   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a Binding for the CheckBox State:

```
 <controls:CheckBox x:Name="chechBox"  DefaultText="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
```

And then, in the ListView ItemTapped event:

```
void OnSelection (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.SelectedItem == null) {
    return; //ItemSelected is called on deselection, which results in SelectedItem being set to null
  }
  var item = (YourModel)e.SelectedItem;
  if(item != null)
  {
     var checkBoxState  = item.IsChecked;
  }
}
```